# in javascript, "this" seems to get lost when function in within an object's object

Tags: javascript, object, scope, this

the object F has a function stored as `this.fn` and `this.state.fn`.  can be called successfully as `f.fn()` but not as `f.state.fn()`

```
function F( i, f ) {
        this.i = i;     
        this.state = { 'fn':f };
        this.f = f;
};                      
F.prototype.inc = function() { this.i++ };
F.prototype.fn = function() { this.state.fn() };
f1 = new F( 1, function() { console.log( this.i ); } );
f1.f();                 // this works
f1.inc();               // this works
f1.state.fn;            // prints the function
f1.fn();                // undefined!
f1.state.fn();          // undefined!
```

the problem seems to be that the function is stored in the object `state`, because this works:

```
f1.state.fn.call( f1 );
F.prototype.fn = function() { this.state.fn.call(this); };
```

which seems to imply that the `this` context within `F.state.fn` is *not* `F` but rather `F.state` - which to me is completely counter-intuitive - is this right!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a function, `this` depends entirely on how you called the function.

When you call a function using dot notation from an object `this` will be automatically set to that object.

If you say `someObject.someChildObject.someFunction()` then within `someFunction()` you'll find `this` will be set to `someChildObject`.

So in your example `f1.fn()` should result in `this` being `f1` within `fn()`, but then within that function you say `this.state.fn()` - which will call `state`'s `fn()` with `this` set to `state`.

You can override this behaviour using `call` or `apply`.

Another example just for your interest:

```
function F( i, f ) {
        this.i = i;     
        this.state = { 'fn':f };
        this.f = f;
};                      
f1 = new F( 1, function() { console.log( this.i ); } );
f1.f();   // works - 'this' will be f1
var x = f1.f; // create a reference to the same function
x();      // won't work - 'this' will probably be 'window'
```

If you create a reference to a function originally defined as an object property and call the function via that reference then `this` will be whatever applies to your new reference. In my example the `x` reference is a global, which in practice means it belongs to the `window` object. What you can learn from this is that the function that `f1.f()` calls doesn't really belong to `f1` at all.

Continuing that example:

```
f2 = {};
f2.i = "hello";
f2.f = f1.f;
f2.f(); // 'this' will be f2, so should log "hello"
```

When you call `f2.f()`, you'll find `this` is set to `f2`, and because I've set a property `f2.i` the function will log that property.

Comment: outstanding!  thank you very much for your enlightenment and the work you put into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/pXLLT/1/)

```
function F(i, f) {
    this.i = i;
    this.state = {
        'fn': f,
        i: 42
    };
    this.f = f;
};
F.prototype.inc = function() {
    this.i++
};
F.prototype.fn = function() {
    this.state.fn()
};
f1 = new F(1, function() {
    console.log(this.i);
});
f1.f(); // this works
f1.inc(); // this works
f1.state.fn; // prints the function
f1.fn(); // 42!
f1.state.fn(); // 42!
```

When you call `state.fn()` it prints `this.i` which is `state.i` which is `42` in my case but `undefined` in your case.

You can alternatively force `this` to not be `state` but to be the object you expect it to be by doing

```
this.state = {
    'fn': f.bind(this)
};
```

`.bind` is ES5 however so you should get the ES5-shim

Comment: absolutely - nice test!  but it still comes back to the fact that `this` is not associated with `F` but rather `F.state` - this (as it were) is what took me by suprise!

Comment: missed `bind` on first read - very cool.  seems to work fine on chrome and ff.

Comment: @cc_young `bind` fails on older browsers. Mainly FF3.6 and IE8. MDN has a shim